# Flutter Web View Published but not working

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, webview, google-play-console

I have just used the flutter web_view library to convert my django full stack web application into mobile app. It is perfectly working on my phone but after publishing the app to google play, I download it, after opening the app it only shows white screen.

What might be the error?

As I discribed, the app is perfectly working when I run it on my phone locally.
After going through all the publification process and creating the release, I uploaded it to google play console. I created afterward open testing were everyone with the google play link can try it.
I and other friends downloaded the app successfully. But after opening it, the screen stays only white.

Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you forget to give the internet permission on **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Yes this was one of the causes it wasn't working actually. Thanks fam.